# Creating a Power Series with Interval of Convergence Given an Interval

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

So I know to determine an interval for a power series, we would use things like the ratio test and then some of the other tests to determine the endpoints but how would you go about doing the reverse?

If we had any such interval like (a,b], [a,b], [a,b), or (a,b), how would you go about creating a power series that would have such an interval?

An observation I was thinking of, since the general expression for a power series contains $(x-c)$ where the series is centered around $c$, we would have it so that $c$ = $(a+b)/2$

Is there a systematic way of doing such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, and you've got a good start on it. 
Start with a power series with radius of convergence $1$ about the origin.
Two questions:

1) How to get get a power series of radius of convergence $c$ from this?

2) How do you move the center of the interval to where you want it?

Hint: Neither of these is hard.

**EDIT**

Example:

Suppose we choose $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}$ as a series with radius of convergence $1$.  How can we change it to get a series of radius of convergence $2$?  All we have to do is change $x$ to $\frac{x}{2}.$   The radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^{-n}x^n}$$ is $2$.  The series converges when $$\left|\frac{x}{2}\right|<1\iff |x|<2.$$

Now suppose that we want a series that converges on the interval $(-1,3).$  As you noted we want a radius of convergence of $2$ and the interval should be centered at $x=1$.  We just constructed a series with radius of convergence $2$, but it is centered at $0$.  To move it to $1$ we just make a Taylor series with the same coefficients, but centered at $1$. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^{-n}(x-1)^n}$$  This converges when $$|x-1|<2\iff -2<x-1<2\iff -1<x<3$$

Comment: I think the power series from $n=1$ to infinity of $\frac{x^n}{n}$ would work, and I think 2) would be done by shifting the center?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how to go about doing this as the series I mentioned has an interval thats closed on one side and open on the other...

Comment: @JL-1 Don't worry about the endpoints at first.  To do what you want in complete generality, you'll have to find one series that converges at both endpoints, one that converges at neither endpoint, and one that converges at one, but not the other.  (It can be the left or the right, because you can flip it around.)  But these are just examples to hunt for.  Then general method of moving the interval is the same.  That's the thing to nail down first.

Comment: I'm not too good at that but while I'm finding the series, assuming I have found all four, how would I change them to conform with any interval?

Comment: @JL-1 That what the two points in my answer are aimed at.  I'll add some more hints.